# Make a working PayPal donate button on android

Tags: android, paypal

I need to make a working donate button for my app..

I have a code that only opens your default android browser with the PayPal URL.

When I open a PayPal url like this: https://www.paypal.com/de/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=J-KMkOXi3P5pwTbuZYELHU8QdzVJGUhGoyIL1DNb8LjuUI71OLDo5u094tG&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8d5c97cbf3d75cb63effe5661cdf3adb6d,
 Then the page tells me a message about something.. but why?

So how can I make a paypal donate button work on android?

Comment: Are you purposely using a German version of paypal? If not then I suggest you go back into your paypal account and look at the instructions on creating a button. You can copy/paste the button from within your paypal account into your app.

Comment: It's not my paypal account

Comment: Where am I supposed to put the source code of the button?

Comment: If the source code is in HTML look for the link, and then if you want to make a button you can use an ImageButton which opens the browser to that link.

Answer (score 0):

The link is not correct, you should generate PayPal payment link in merchant's account. follow steps1-6 in https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/add-payment-link-to-facebook